# Plotting 2 variables from one column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a dataframe with several columns, on of which is gender, (male, female). I'd like to get a line plot of both variable against a third, in this case income, I have the following code:

```
ax = plt.gca()

df.plot(kind='line', x='income', y=[df.gender=='male'], ax=ax)
df.plot(kind='line', x='income', y=[df.gender =='female'], color='red', ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

And I keep getting a Value error. 
I think I should be using a bar chart??
Any thoughts?

Comment: try changing it to `df[df.gender =='male'].plot(x='income', y='your_field`)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a groupby+unstack. Assuming you have a male and female observation for each income value, the following code should get you what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['male',2,3],
                  ['female',2,8],
                  ['male',5,9],
                  ['female',5,8],
                  ['male',7,4],
                  ['female',7,3]], columns = ['gender', 'income', 'debt'])
df.groupby(['gender', 'income'])['debt'].mean().unstack(level=0).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you

Comment: No problem. Please upvote/accept this answer if your problem is solved.